# Remove ul wrap on sidebars - Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

Whenever I call my sidebar, it's always wrapped in `<ul>` and `</ul>`, this is affecting my theme and I can't find out how to remove it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**In your theme directory:** edit `sidebar.php` and delete the opening `<ul>` and closing `</ul>` tags. I don't recommend this, because it will leave orphaned `<li>` tags, which is not well-formed HTML. A better solution is to edit your sidebar `<ul>`'s style in `style.css` so that it's no longer "affected".

See [`<ul>`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_ul.asp) tag.